# scss target multiple IDs

Tags: css, sass

I wish to target classes within ID's using scss so that my compiled css is as follows:

```
#template1 .heroText, #template2 .heroText {
    text-align:center;
}
#template3 .heroText, #template4 .heroText {
    text-align:left;
}
```

The following scss (comma separated IDs) does not appear to be working for me:

```
#template1, #template2{
    .heroText {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
#template3, #template4{
    .heroText {
        text-align:left;
    }
}
```

Should this be working or is there a different way to target multiple IDs in scss, as all the documentation I can find related to classes not ID's

Comment: @VXp thanks and ammened

Comment: Nesting can get a real PITA with SASS... Did you check what css is produced from your scss file?

Comment: It should work. Do you have any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It should work, what css does that produce?

Comment: Yes. If I paste your SCSS into a codepen and click "View compiled CSS", the code above is exactly what I get. So what goes wrong? Compilation errors? Wrong CSS output? Is it a caching problem (i.e. your browser sees an older version of the css)? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, I tracked the issue down to the .sass-cache folder. Upon deleting this my compiled css is showing as expected once I run grunt against my scss.